# Как вставить placeholder в textbox? в zk framework 6.5.2

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, placeholder

```
               <row>
                    <label value="ФИО" />
                    <textbox id="client_name1" mold="rounded"
                        disabled="true" hflex="1"
                     value="@{dper_infomain$composer.current.client_name1}" 
                     placeholder="Введите Имя" />                          
                    <textbox id="client_name2" mold="rounded"
                        disabled="true" hflex="1"

                    value="@{dper_infomain$composer.current.client_name2}" 
                    placeholder="Введите Фамилию" />
                    <textbox id="client_name3" mold="rounded"
                        disabled="true" hflex="1"

                    value="@{dper_infomain$composer.current.client_name3}" 
                    placeholder="Введите Отчество" />
                    <label value="Резидент" />
                    <rcombobox id="rezident" mold="rounded"
                        disabled="true" hflex="1"

                selecteditem="@{dper_infomain$composer.current.rezident}" />
                </row>
```

> 

- > Не удалось загрузить /dper_info.zul
  >          Причина: Method setPlaceholder not found for class    org.zkoss.zul.Textbox
  >   org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.PropertyNotFoundException: Method
  >   setPlaceholder not found for class org.zkoss.zul.Textbox  at
  >   org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.resolve(Property.java:190)  at
  >   org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign0(Property.java:206)  at
  >   org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign(Property.java:173)   at
  >   org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.applyProperties(ComponentInfo.java:829)
  >         at    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComponent(AbstractUiFactory.java:96)

Comment: `placeholder="Введите Фамилию/>` - где закрывающая кавычка?

Comment: Это ошибка не из за ковычки

Comment: проверьте свой код тут -> https://www.zkoss.org/zksandbox/
какой иде пользуетесь?